# Rails belongs_to association on model name that has underscores

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hey guys I broke a bit of rails convention by using underscores instead of camelcasing on a class name (Ui_1_Log instead of Ui1Log) and now when I refer to the association it isnt finding the right class.  For example:

```
class Ui_1_Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ui_1_logs
end
```

Now when I call the association in the rails console it doesnt work because it returns a classname as Camelcase when it needs to keep the underscores...

```
x = Account.first
x.ui_1_logs.first  #returns nameError: uninitialized constant Account::Ui1Log
```

It needs to be Account::Ui_1_Log but I don't know how to force that...Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the *class name* on the *association* with `class_name` option.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ui_1_logs, class_name: 'Ui_1_Log'
end
```

But I still recommend to follow *conventions*.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!